# Foreach loop javascript failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this each statement cause my code to break? Also do I have to set an index with javascript?

```
var email = [];

email['update'] = true;
email['e_case_id'] = $("#e_case").val();

var i = 0;

$.each($('.rowChecked'), function() {
    email['e_attachments'][i] = $(this).attr('id');
    i++;
});
```

Comment: do you get any errors in console? Also, .each's function can take index, value, so you don't really even need that i++ in there. just declare function(i, v){ ... }

Comment: Javascript does not support associative arrays. So you can not simply do `email['update'] = true;` As discussed in some answers below you can use a literal object like an associative array: `myLiteralObject = {}; myLiterObject["associativeStyleKey"] = "whatever";`

Comment: @Mike: actually it would work anyway because an `Array` is also an object.

Comment: except the code looks like it's trying to iterate through a list of attachments.  This doesn't look right

Comment: @Claudiu: Yes, it works until you try to loop through the array, as the `each` method will only loop through the array items, not the object properties.

Comment: @Guffa: oh wow jQuery made it do something more intelligent - awesome! I didn't know.

Comment: @Claudiu: Well, it would if the code would use the `email` array in the loop, but it loops through a jQuery object as an array, which makes very little sense...

Comment: @Guffa: yep, I meant jQuery made `$.each()` do something intelligent on arrays (as opposed to the native `for...in` loop), not that the code in the question does something intelligent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, `email` should be an object literal, not an array literal:

```
var email = {};
```

Secondly, you didn't define `email['e_attachments']` before you tried to use it. This is likely what's prevent it from working. Try adding

```
email['e_attachments'] = [];
```

Before the `$.each`.

---

You can use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) in this circumstance, btw. That is:

```
email['e_attachments'] = $.map($('.rowChecked'), function (el) { 
    return $(el).attr('id'); 
});
```

Instead of your `$.each`. Or better yet:

```
email['e_attachments'] = $('.rowChecked').map(function () { 
    return $(this).attr('id'); 
}
```